# How to create a single download link for 2 pdf files in php

Tags: php

I'm very new to PHP and wanted to know how to create a single download link for 2 pdf files using php. Do I need to write an individual download.php file to execute or can I simply add it to my index page using an  tag in html? I need it to work across all browsers.

I have 2 documents that are in their own folder named "forms" and not sure how to create a simple text link that will let a user download both documents in a single click.

Comment: It is not good practice and UX, you should show 2 separate download links, or zip them together

Comment: You could achieve this with JavaScript, but it would be really weird behaviour. As others already said, the most popular solution is archiving files via ZIP and then linking the archive.

Comment: I understand now about it not being good practice to download 2 individual files in one link. I can do either way of a zip file with both or add 2 individual links.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with the other answers, this is not the best practice, you should use one button/link for each file, it's even easier to understand what's been displayed for the user. You should probably use two icons or links.

Look up for w3schools, they have good tutorials of how to use icons, links, html, css and javascript.

There are some links:

https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_links.asp 
https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/w3css_icons.asp 
https://www.w3schools.com/icons/fontawesome5_icons_computers.asp

Comment: Thank you for these links! But when I tried to follow the directions the link doesn't seem to download anything. The files are in a publicly accessible place so not sure what the issue is? Would I have to have an additional download.php file to have it function?